# Why was this question regarding the authenticity of a video, put on hold?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23927/did-this-cnn-interview-with-a-boy-who-was-an-isis-hostage-say-he-supported-them#23927) question under a guest account and it was put on hold. I'm asking if a video is authentic, in the sense that it represents what it says it does. It was put on hold for the following reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:
>
> "Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under
>   investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar
>   investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data
>   for a meaningful answer. For more information, see Handling current
>   news questions." – Sklivvz

I fail to see how this relates to the question (in question).

Can somebody explain?

Comment: I've commented under the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've commented under the question, but I'm reproducing here for completeness:

> What kind of evidence do you expect? If a single news source says something, it clearly is a very weak claim, and should not be taken as "true" -- I was taught this in middle school!
>
> If you are looking for some "posterior" evidence, like some historical context, then certainly there can be no such evidence now.
>
> These questions are "on hold" because we have dozens of them, and they either have no answer, or have incredibly poor answers because there's no evidence. It's clear we are not helping anyone if we accept stuff we can't answer.

We don't allow *original research*. We don't allow *personal opinions*. We are not *video experts* or *news experts*.

**We are experts at finding evidence** -- but it's extremely unlikely there is any objective evidence beyond what's already presented. If you (or anyone else) has some hard evidence with which to answer, let us know and we'll open the question.